# XMLHttpRequest not fetching values before all alerts are being closed

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch a value from another page using XMLHttpRequest and I found that the value is only fetched after all alerts has been closed in the following script:

```
function changePw_prompt() {
    var success = false;
    while(!success) {
        var newPassword = prompt("Please enter a new password", "");
        if (newPassword != null) {
            replyMsg = sendPassword(newPassword);
            if (replyMsg == "CHNGSUCC") {
                alert("Password changed");
                sucess = true;
            } else if (replyMsg == "CHNGFAIL") {
                alert("Error: Password is shorter than 8 characters.");
                sucess = false;
            } else if (replyMsg == "CHNGERROR") {
                alert("Internal error, please contact server admin.");
                sucess = true;
            }
        } else {
            alert("Password unchanged");
            success = true;
        }
    }

}

function sendPassword(pwd) {
    alert("Run 2nd function");
    var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
            var reply2 = xmlhttp2.responseText;
            alert(reply2);
            return reply2;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp2.open("POST","changepw.php",true);
    xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp2.send("uid="+document.getElementById("amsnr").value+"&pwd="+pwd);   
}
```

I would like to know what is wrong here. Also, how should I change my code if I want to have a correct value returned for `replyMsg` variable, which fetches the response from another page.

Thanks.

*Updated* I have modified my code to make it simpler but it is still not working, the code is as followings, how should I modify it to keep my original purpose using a callback function?

```
function changePw_prompt() {
    var success = false;
    while(!success) {
        var replyMsg = "";
        var newPassword = prompt("Please enter a new password", "");
        if (newPassword != null) {
            var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
                    var replyMsg = xmlhttp2.responseText;
                    alert(replyMsg);
                    if (replyMsg == "CHNGSUCC") {
                        alert("Password changed");
                        sucess = true;
                    } else if (replyMsg == "CHNGFAIL") {
                        alert("Error: Password is shorter than 8 characters.");
                        sucess = false;
                    } else if (replyMsg == "CHNGERROR") {
                        alert("Internal error, please contact server admin.");
                        sucess = true;
                    }   
                }
            }
            xmlhttp2.open("POST","changepw.php",true);
            xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp2.send("uid="+document.getElementById("amsnr").value+"&pwd="+newPassword);

        } else {
            alert("Password unchanged");
            success = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is purpose of using `while` loop?

Comment: That is to make sure that if the user input something incorrect (e.g. password shorter than 8 characters long) then it will repeat the whole thing again to prompt the user to input another password.

Comment: You are mixing sync code (alert) and async code (ajax). Inside async code you can return a promise or you can send a callback as argument that you will call when you have a value. Of course, you will need to refactor your code.

Comment: What about the new block of code that I have just uploaded? How should I change it?

Comment: the onreadystatechange callback (async) is still outside of your sync while loop. outside in terms of "time", not line of code.

Comment: Then how should I change it to make it inside the loop?

Comment: Once you call an async function, the only time you can continue to run code is inside the callback. So changePw_prompt() could be without a loop, it will check the password, do the ajax call, inside the onreadystatechange, if the answer is wrong, then you recall changePw_prompt().

Comment: Thank you, that worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
/**
 * Call Example
 * changePw_prompt(function(changed) { console.log("password changed? ", changed); })
 */
/**
 * @param function continueCallback : will run with the argument false/true 
 */
function changePw_prompt(continueCallback) {
    var newPassword = prompt("Please enter a new password", "");
    if (newPassword == null) {
            alert("Password unchanged");
            continueCallback(false);
    } else {
            var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
                    var replyMsg = xmlhttp2.responseText;
                    alert(replyMsg);
                    if (replyMsg == "CHNGSUCC") {
                        alert("Password changed");
                        continueCallback(true);
                    } else if (replyMsg == "CHNGFAIL") {
                        alert("Error: Password is shorter than 8 characters.");

                        // repeat the process
                        changePw_prompt(continueCallback);
                    } else if (replyMsg == "CHNGERROR") {
                        alert("Internal error, please contact server admin.");
                        continueCallback(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp2.open("POST","changepw.php",true);
            xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var uid = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("amsnr").value);
            var pwd = encodeURIComponent(newPassword);
            xmlhttp2.send("uid="+uid+"&pwd="+pwd);
    }
}
```